# Do Karush Kuhn Tucker $\mu$ conditions have to be unique?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

In KKT, we have some optimal point $x^*$ with associated $\mu^*$ value for inequality constraints. Are these $\mu^*$ values unique for a given $x^*$ (for the primal problem)?

It seems that when these constraints turn active (you go from inequality to equality constraint) the exact magnitude of $\mu^*$ doesn't actually matter since you are bound by primal feasibility anyways (specifically $g(x) \leq 0$) so you can't improve your score by moving in the direction of the $f(x)$ gradient when it becomes perfectly opposing $g(x)$. Thus, although your solution for a $\mu < \mu*$ on an active constraint no longer satisfies the lagrangian gradient $= 0$ condition but is nontheless a local optimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale of $\mu$ is bound by stationarity, indeed when you have the derivative of the Lagragian equal to $0$, the term $\mu^T\partial g(x)=b(x)$ has a unique solution with the additional constraint of dual feasibility and complementary slackness making sure that some $\mu_i$ are $0$. The solution is unique since active constraints must have independent normal directions.

Comment: Sorry, when we solve the dual problem, are there not multiple $\mu$ that satisfy the constraint though? Since any $\mu$ of a particular direction satisfies the dual by complementary slackness (Since the dual is not defined as the gradient of the lagrangian being 0, but just based on maximizing the lagrangian based on $\mu$ choice).

Comment: I do not understand your question, however the dual has exactly the same KKT conditions and the same argument applies.